# Site responsivo não se adapta no celular

Tags: layout-responsivo

Fiz um site responsivo, testando em sites que simulam um celular, mas quando abro em um celular de verdade ele não se adapta continua na versão para computador.

http://courier-keith-62774.bitballoon.com

Comment: Vc não precisa testar em "sites que simulam celular". O Chrome e o Firefox, por exemplo, existe ferramenta pra isso com F12.

Comment: Foram só os testes, fiz eles usando esse recurso também.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adicione esta linha ao `<head></head>`:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0,user-scalable=no" />
```

Comment: Putz, vlw David, tinha me esquecido de recolocar essa meta tag, Obrigado.